# Using jQuery to change href link causes CORS policy Blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web page that dynamically adds content as the user scrolls down.  As a part of this process I will have 'a' elements that have been added to the DOM and then I want to give them an href link dynamically. The problem is that I get this error from Google Chrome.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4NRJoCNHIs' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4NRJoCNHIs with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Here is an example of the code that causes this problem.

```
article.find('a').each(function() {
     $(this).attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4NRJoCNHIs");
     $(this).attr("target","_blank");
```

When I ran the debugger I saw that the href attribute was successfully changed, but Chrome throws the error shortly after and deletes the element entirely.

I don't understand how adding a link dynamically breaks CORS policy.  If anyone has any advice to prevent the error from appearing or has a better method to dynamically edit href attributes please let me know.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I solved the problem!  After being told that javascript must be making an XMLHttpRequest without me knowing it and thought about what libraries I was using and I realized that jScroll, the library I use to add content to the page when the user scrolls to the bottom, does make a GET request to the href of the last 'a' tag on the page.  This makes sense, because to normally use jScroll the last 'a' tag should have an href leading to the next html page you want to load.  Thank you to everyone for their help!

Comment: I don't think it's the dynamic adding of links to the page that creates cors problem, considering that every link in a page built with for example Angular is dynamically generated and added via javascript. Could be that Chrome or some extension you use are blocking the behaviour as it might look like browser hi-jacking when you try to replace every link in a page with a link to the same youtube video. Just a thought, might be worth google for.

Comment: A link doesn't use `XMLHttpRequest`, javascript does

Comment: hmm, I just tested the site in Firefox, where I don't have any extensions, and I still get the "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error.

So, why would javascript be making a `XMLHttpRequest` when I am just editing the href of an element?

Comment: charlietfl, I was able to solve the problem thanks to your help.  Thank you!  I left an edit explaining what happened.

Comment: If you solved it, add it as an Answer, not a change to your question. The solution does not form part of the original problem! This is a Q&A site, so please follow the format. You're allowed to answer your own question, and also others can then vote on that answer...so it's in your interest :-). Thanks

Comment: I did not know that.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own questions because I figured out the problem thanks to the wonderful help here!  Changing an href should never make a GET request on the link.  So, I looked for where there might be other code that would try and access the href.  I figured out that jScroll was trying to use the 'a' tag to generate new page content and as a result jScroll was making GET requests on the links as they were being changed.